# Angular 7 - jQuery Plugin, can't find function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm currently trying to use a jQuery plugin, called [cube portfolio](https://codecanyon.net/item/cube-portfolio-responsive-jquery-grid-plugin/6372959).

So far I've added the plugins directory to my assets folder, added its JS and CSS to `angular.json`, and tried the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as AOS from 'aos';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as cubeportfolio from 'src/assets/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all',
  templateUrl: './all.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all.component.scss']
})
export class AllComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    AOS.init();

    $('#js-grid-masonry').cubeportfolio({
      filters: '#js-filters-masonry',
      layoutMode: 'grid',
      defaultFilter: '*',
      animationType: 'slideDelay',
      gapHorizontal: 20,
      gapVertical: 20,
      gridAdjustment: 'responsive',
      mediaQueries: [{
        width: 1500,
        cols: 5,
      }, {
        width: 1100,
        cols: 4,
      }, {
        width: 800,
        cols: 3,
      }, {
        width: 480,
        cols: 2,
        options: {
          caption: '',
          gapHorizontal: 10,
          gapVertical: 10,
        }
      }],
      caption: 'overlayBottomAlong',
      displayType: 'bottomToTop',
      displayTypeSpeed: 100,

      // lightbox
      lightboxDelegate: '.cbp-lightbox',
      lightboxGallery: true,
      lightboxTitleSrc: 'data-title',
      lightboxCounter: '<div class="cbp-popup-lightbox-counter">{{current}} of {{total}}</div>',
    });

  }

}
```

**Somehow the JS doesn't seem to work - following error show up in the console:**

> ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__(...).cubeportfolio is not a function.

Further code:

```
"styles": [
    "src/assets/cubeportfolio/css/cubeportfolio.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "src/assets/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"
]
```

Comment: You should never try to mix Jquery with any framework. You should try to find a native version or an Angular version of the plugin you are trying to install.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of jquery?

Comment: @DEVCNN Yes: "jquery": "^3.4.0"

Comment: @Nicolas Do you know any plugin such as cube portfolio?

Comment: The thing is i can't find a cdn for this. Have you bought this?

Comment: @DEVCNN Yes, it's bought. The JS starts like this (in case that helps): `(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    function CubePortfolio(obj, options, callback) {`

Comment: The first rule of Angular is don't jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

If your are really determine to introduce the misery of jQuery use ngAfterViewInit, not ngOnInit as the DOM doesn't exist yet.

Get rid of

```
import * as cubeportfolio from 'src/assets/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.js';
```

as importing jQuery plugin scripts extend the jQuery object and should not be imported.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it still shows the same error. However, I'd love to use an alternative which is not jQuery. Do know of any portfolio plugin which is suitable for Angular? What about Javascript plugins?